# Nested child key query in FirebaseAnimatedList

Tags: android, flutter

My Firebase Structure is like this:

[image]

I want to get 'groupName' list in FirebaseAnimatedList.

How to achive this?

**My current code:**

```
chatGroupNameReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("chat_group_message_user_info").child(widget.user.uid);


body: new Container(
    child: new Flexible(
      child: new FirebaseAnimatedList(
        query: chatGroupNameReference,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        defaultChild: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,),),
        itemBuilder: (_, DataSnapshot messageSnapshot,
            Animation<double> animation, int index) {

          return Text("Group Name will be here")
        },
      ),
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For nested child key query we need FutureBuilder with FirebaseAnimatedList:**

```
chatGroupNameReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("chat_group_message_user_info").child(widget.user.uid);

body: new FirebaseAnimatedList(
    defaultChild: Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator()),
    query: chatGroupNameReference,
    sort: (a,b) => (b.key.compareTo(a.key)),
    itemBuilder: (_, DataSnapshot messageSnapshot, Animation<double> animation, int index) {

      return new FutureBuilder<DataSnapshot>(
        future: chatGroupNameReference.child(messageSnapshot.key).once(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot){

          return snapshot.hasData ? new Text(snapshot.data.value['groupName']) : new Text("");
        },
      );
    },
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(_, DataSnapshot messageSnapshot,
        Animation<double> animation, int index)
```

After that line you can use `FutureBuilder` to get data from your Firebase Database.

For example like that [In a firebase animated list, is there a way to let firebase list know the expected height of a widget before it loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44479214)