# Firebase: use multiple child in DatabaseReference

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, data-sharing

I need to make multiple query the field is .child() in FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference()

For example, I want it to work like this:

```
         final _itemRef2 = FirebaseDatabase.instance
         .reference()
         .child('lists')
         .child('-Mdso4T8PFejXPXjVhpW','-MdshmYfuEeZWK_hNwZe','-Mdsi6vSVHAmRbxoELNm')
         .child('items');
```

Of course, it doesn't work

**I don't understand how do I use the list of values in .child? What solution should I use?**

Then, i want use _itemRef2 in FirebaseAnimatedList like this:

```
          Flexible(
           child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
             query: _itemRef2,
               itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,
                             DataSnapshot snapshot,
                             Animation<double> animation,
                             int index) {
                             return ListTile(
```

Comment: Hi WestDay, can you share the codes instead using the images?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass multiple values in `child` that way. You'll have to make separate requests for each node

```
final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("lists");
     
databaseReference.child("list_id_1").once(),
databaseReference.child("list_id_2").once()
```

You can try using [`Future.wait()`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.13.4/dart-async/Future/wait.html) to run all Futures simultaneously.

Comment: Ok. And how to use it correctly in FirebaseAnimatedList ()?

Comment: @WestDay is there any specific query you are trying to make? Like is there any common property in those 3 lists? Then you can use `.equalTo` in that case. Otherwise [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52257130/13130697) explains using a FutureBuilder in FirebaseAnimatedList.